# How to access camera onclick on Android app?

Tags: javascript, android, html

I am currently using Visual Studio to work on my project, and i need a function which allows the opening of camera on the press of a button. I have some codes from a previous project but they don't seem to work now. Below are my codes.

js:

```
function getImage() {
    // Retrieve image file location from specified source
    navigator.camera.getPicture(uploadPhoto,
        function (message) { alert('get picture failed'); },
        { quality: 10, destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI, sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY }
    );
}
```

HTML:

```
<form id="buyforme">

<img id="myimg" height="100">
<input type="button" name="selectimg" id="selectimg" onclick="getImage();" value="Take a picture of this item :)">
```

Please advise & let me know if there's anything else you need to know! Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

For access to mobile phone camera for getting `photo` or `video` in `android` or `ios` you can simply use `input[type="file"]` like this:

**Getting photo:**

```
 <input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera">
```

**Getting video:**

```
<input type="file" name="video" accept="video/*" capture="environment">
```

**For opening back camera:**

```
<input type="file" name="image" accept="image/*" capture="environment">
```

**And for selfie camera (front):**

```
<input type="file" name="image" accept="image/*" capture="user">
```

**[Source](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-media-capture/)**